# migrating from apollo 2 - mergeSchemas doesn't except GraphQLSchema

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I'm using Apollo 1 server, and i'm trying to migrate to Apollo 2.
My project includes 2 simple GraphQLSchema:

```
const missionSchema = new GraphQLSchema({query: missionQuery, mutation: missionMutation});
const userSchema = new GraphQLSchema({query: userQuery, mutation: userMutation});
```

While this stitching worked in Apollo 1 -

```
    const schema = mergeSchemas({ schemas: [ missionSchema, userSchema ] });
```

It throws an error in apollo 2 -

> ....Type 'GraphQLSchema' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLNamedType[]'.
>     Property 'includes' is missing in type 'GraphQLSchema'.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was some kind of typescript issue - removing node-modules, and deleting this plugin ts-graphql-plugin did the trick.